# My NavBar in NextJs is not working when clicking to dropdown

Tags: next.js

I have a Navbar in folder 'app/components/NabBar.tsx' this is the code:

```
"use client"
import { useUser } from '../../context/UserContext.js'
import { logo } from '../../public/logo.js'

function NavBar() {
    const user = useUser();
    if (!user || !user.email) return null;
    return (
        <div>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.1/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav className="bg-white border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
<div className="max-w-screen-xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-4">
<a href="#" className="flex items-center">
<img src={logo} className="h-8 mr-3" alt="Fagar Logo" />
</a>
<button data-collapse-toggle="navbar-multi-level" type="button" className="inline-flex items-center p-2 w-10 h-10 justify-center text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-controls="navbar-multi-level" aria-expanded="false">
<span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
<svg className="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 17 14">
<path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M1 1h15M1 7h15M1 13h15" />
</svg>
</button>
<div className="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto" id="navbar-multi-level">
<ul className="flex flex-col font-medium p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
<li>
<a href="#" className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white bg-blue-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:text-blue-500 dark:bg-blue-600 md:dark:bg-transparent" aria-current="page">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<button id="dropdownNavbarLink" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownNavbar" className="flex items-center justify-between w-full py-2 pl-3 pr-4  text-gray-700 border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:w-auto dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:focus:text-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Insumos <svg className="w-2.5 h-2.5 ml-2.5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
<path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4" />
                                </svg></button>
                                <div id="dropdownNavbar" className="z-10 hidden font-normal bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600">
                                    <ul className="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400" aria-labelledby="dropdownLargeButton">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Dashboard</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li aria-labelledby="dropdownNavbarLink">
                                            <button id="doubleDropdownButton" data-dropdown-toggle="doubleDropdown" data-dropdown-placement="right-start" type="button" className="flex items-center justify-between w-full px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Insumos<svg className="w-2.5 h-2.5 ml-2.5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
                                                <path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4" />
                                            </svg></button>
                                            <div id="doubleDropdown" className="z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700">
                                                <ul className="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="doubleDropdownButton">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white">Cajas</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Earnings</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div className="py-1">
                                        <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Services</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </nav>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.1/flowbite.min.js"></script>

        </div>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

as you can see that is the NavBar, so I import it in the src/app/layout.tsx

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { UserProvider, useUser } from '../context/UserContext.js'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import { logo } from '../public/logo.js'
import Head from 'next/head';


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Admon - Fagar Comercial',
  description: 'Web App',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children, }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <UserProvider>
          <div>
            <Head>
              <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.1/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            </Head>
            <NavBar />
          </div>
          {children}
        </UserProvider>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.1/flowbite.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html >
  )
}
```

The navBar shows itself fine, but the dropdown does not work

If I copy the navBar code and paste in layout instead of  it works the dropdown, I am using flowbite

Any ideas?

I also tried not to put the cdns in the layout.tsx as this

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { UserProvider, useUser } from '../context/UserContext.js'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import { logo } from '../public/logo.js'
import Head from 'next/head';


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Admon - Fagar Comercial',
  description: 'Web App',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children, }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <UserProvider>
          <div>
            <Head>
            </Head>
            <NavBar />
          </div>
          {children}
        </UserProvider>  
      </body>
    </html >
  )
}
```